# Navigation drawer getting open after coming back from other screen

Tags: android, react-native, navigation-drawer, back-button, react-native-navigation

I am using Wix's react-native-navigation V2. In my navigation drawer there is one component name after pressing on it I am going to the next screen and after pressing back button I am coming back but drawer getting opened.

Following is the code of my home screen which have the right button to open navigation drawer.

```
export default class Boiler extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.isSideDrawerVisible = false;
        Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
    }

    navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
        if (buttonId === "buttonOne") {
            (!this.isSideDrawerVisible) ? this.isSideDrawerVisible = true : this.isSideDrawerVisible = false
            Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
                sideMenu: {
                    left: {
                        visible: this.isSideDrawerVisible,
                    }
                }
            });
            this.isSideDrawerVisible = false
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Hello</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

following is the code of my home screen's setRoot

```
Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
            sideMenu: {
                left: {
                    component: {
                        name: 'SideDrawer',
                        passProps: {
                            text: 'This is a left side menu screen'
                        }
                    }
                },
                center: {
                    stack: {
                        id: 'mainStack',
                        children: [
                            {
                                stack: {
                                    id: 'tab1Stack',
                                    children: [
                                      {
                                        component: {
                                          name: 'Home'
                                        }
                                      }
                                    ],
                                    options: {
                                      topBar: {
                                        leftButtons: [
                                          {
                                            id: 'buttonOne',
                                            icon: sources[0]
                                          }
                                        ],
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                },
                        ],

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I am not getting after coming back to the main home screen then why the navigation drawer is getting opened.

and the following is the code for after pressing text on navigation-drawer

```
goNew = () => {
    this.goClose()
      Navigation.push('mainStack', {
        component: {
          name: 'NewComp',
          passProps: {
            text: 'Pushed screen'
          },
          options: {
            topBar: {
              title: {
                text: 'New Component'
              }
            },
            sideMenu: {
              left: {
              enabled: false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Please help if anyone can. thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to close drawer when item or button selected for next function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens when you open your navigation drawer (sidemenu) on pressing of button is component say `homescreen`  like

```
 navigationButtonPressed({ buttonId }) {
           if(buttonId == 'menu'){                  
                  Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
                        sideMenu:{
                              left:{
                                    visible:true
                              }
                        }
                  })
            }
   }
```

and close the sidemenu by swiping right/left.
At this stage the option in navigation for `homescreen` is

```
         sideMenu:{
             left:{
                 visible:true
             }
         }
```

so when your `homescreen` component re appears in stack, the sidemenu will appear as the result of the `visible` option

**the solution to this is in `homescreen` component**
`subscribe to navigation events`

```
 constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            Navigation.events().bindComponent(this); 
 }
```

and in your `componentDidDisappear()`

```
 Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId,{
            sideMenu:{
                left:{
                      visible:false
                }
          }
        })
```

**where `this.props.componentId` is the id of your `homescreen` component**

Answer (score 0):

In your Navigation drawer function where you are pushing the new screen, you just need to close the drawer before pushing it like:

```
goNew = () => {
  Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
    sideMenu: {
      left: {
        visible: false
      }
    }
  })
    Navigation.push('mainStack', {
      component: {
        name: 'NewComp',
        passProps: {
          text: 'Pushed screen'
        },
        options: {
          topBar: {
            title: {
              text: 'New Component'
            }
          },
          sideMenu: {
            left: {
            enabled: false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

where `this.props.componentId` is nothing but the component id for your drawer created by default by react-native-navigation.

Comment: thanks, but I did the same `this.goClose` contains merge option for closing

Comment: can you post your `this,goClose` function as well

Comment: `Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
      sideMenu: {
        left: {
          visible: false,
        }
      }
    });`

Comment: it is same as yours